# Polygon colors overlap when zoom in the google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, dictionary, google-maps-api-3

I have posted this question in Stackoverflow previously with a different heading, but did not got much response. Posting this time again with some more clarification.

I have implemented a google map using V3 js API. I am drawing about 500 zip code polygons inside the map. The coloring of the zip code polygons depends upon certain conditions which is working fine. Like I am assigning distinct colors to a set of zipcodes. But the problem is when I am zoom in the map some of the polygon colors overlap with other polygon colors.

For ex: I am pulling 30 zipcodes from my DB. I am dividing those 30 zipcodes into 5 regions(say depending upon highest sales to lowest sales). Each region will be marked by a particular color.Thus in this case 30 polygons will be plotted with 5 regions so as having 5 different colors. Now when I am zooming up the map there is no change in the grouping, but some of the polygon(may be 3-4) colors overlap to other polygons. If number 3 region has color "Yellow" in normal map, when I zoom in the map some of the polygons of region 3 get overlapped by "Red" color. Where as "Red" color belongs to region 1 zip code polygons.

Here is the code

```
{% ifequal zip.rank 1 %}
    var fillColor = '#FF0000';
{% endifequal %}
{% ifequal zip.rank 2 %}
    var fillColor = '#FF00D3';
{% endifequal %}
{% ifequal zip.rank 3 %}
    var fillColor = '#BE4BAA';
{% endifequal %}
{% ifequal zip.rank 4 %}
    var fillColor = '#BE88B5';
{% endifequal %}
{% ifequal zip.rank 5 %}
    var fillColor = '#857081';
{% endifequal %}


var path = [
                {% for polycoord in zip.zip_info.zip_polygon %}
                    new google.maps.LatLng({{polycoord.1}}, {{polycoord.0}}),
                {% endfor %}
            ];
var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon(
    {
        path:path, 
        clickable:true,
        strokeColor: '#000000',
        strokeOpacity: 0.75,
        strokeWeight: 1,
        fillColor: fillColor,
        fillOpacity: 1,
    }

);
polygon.setMap(map);
```

Comment: Hard to answer without seeing any code, a link to the map would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the solution. Basically all the colors were generated randomly through a server side script, and were passed to the map template. The script which was used to generate random colors, sometimes gave 5 digit color code, which browser was not able to understand. Thus some of the polygon regions were taking the nearby polygon region colors. Now I have modified the server side script so that if the script generates 5 digit color code, then an extra random digit will be added to the color code, which will eventually make a valid color code.